# HTML view cannot see AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a backend call using AngularJS using AJAX. My call returns the JSON successfully. This code is written in a JavaScript file.

I have a html file in the same code base which is unable to iterate through this JSON.
My JavaScript snippet is as below:

```
        angular.module('kmapp').controller("FieldCodesCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){

                var model =  {};

                console.log("FieldCodesCtrl");
                $http.get("/my/rest/URL").success(function (data) {
                    model.items = data;
                    console.log("data set on items");
                    $scope.fieldCodes = model;
                    console.log($scope.fieldCodes.items.length);
                });


               // $scope.fieldCodes = model;

            }]);
```

My html is as below:

```
            <tr ng-repeat="item in fieldCodes.items">
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.comment}}</td>
            </tr>
```

My issue is that the "fieldCodes.items" has nothing in the html. So it does not display the ID and Comment that I get from my JSON.

Can someone please help. I am new to AngularJS. So please excuse me if it is something obvious.

Comment: What about when you do just item in fieldCodes? Kindly post your json

Comment: initialize your property $scope.fieldCodes before you $http. Then when you alter its value the html will respond.

Comment: i think you should define the variable before $http.

Comment: Here is my JSON: {
    fieldCodes: {
        items: [{
            id: XXX
            name: CCC
            value: DD
            comment: AA
        }, {
            id: aaaa
            name: aaaaadd
            value: ddf
            comment: ee
        }]
    }
}

Comment: Define before $http does not help :(

Comment: $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.fieldCodes.items = data;console.log("data set on items");}) inside the AJAX call did the magic!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using model.items = data; , Use model = data; Otherwise it will not defined properly. As you are using in your view (model bind) item.id looks ok. so try with this (model = data) Hope this will work. I can Answer you more specify, If you can sent the sample JSON.

Thanks
\Riyadh

Comment: {
    fieldCodes: {
        items: [{
            id: XXX
            name: CCC
            value: DD
            comment: AA
        }, {
            id: aaaa
            name: aaaaadd
            value: ddf
            comment: ee
        }]
    }
}

Comment: model = data does not help :(

Comment: @SSM Did you try model = data.fieldCodes?

Answer (score 1):

$http needs to be injected into your controller.

```
.controller("FieldCodesCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
```

Make sure you have your module registered to the HTML tag in the document. I think it is something like "ng-app."

Comment: Does not help :( Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm looking at this wrong, but it seems that you are assigning this object to `model.items`

```
{ fieldCodes: { 
    items: [
        { id: XXX name: CCC value: DD comment: AA }, 
        { id: aaaa name: aaaaadd value: ddf comment: ee }] 
    }
}
```

Wouldn't you instead want `model = data.fieldCodes;` to be able to use `fieldCodes.items`?

Comment: $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.fieldCodes.items = data;console.log("data set on items");}) inside the AJAX call did the magic!

Comment: If you have to run $apply, you should rethink your methods. Look into encompassing your $http (or $resource) call in a service. Then , return the results. That way $apply is automatically applied.